# iOS13 external screen mirroring, getting error: setScreen should not be called

Tags: ios, ios13, swift5, airplay

I am trying to present a custom view controller to external connected screen in iOS 13. I followed this tutorial:

http://www.spazstik-software.com/blog/article/how-to-display-custom-content-on-a-external-screen-from-a-ios-device

I have following code:

```
/// A private method used to setup a external screen with a window
/// loaded with a ExternalScreenViewController
///
/// - parameter screen: A UIScreen object to connect the
/// ExternalScreenViewController too
private func setupExternalScreen(screen: UIScreen) {
  guard externalWindow == nil,
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExternalScreen") as? ExternalScreenViewController else {
      return
  }

  externalWindow = UIWindow(frame: screen.bounds)
  externalWindow!.rootViewController = vc
  externalWindow!.screen = screen
  externalWindow!.hidden = false
}
```

In the line `externalWindow!.screen = screen` I am getting an error in the Xcode 11.4.1 console:

**[Assert] Error in UIKit client: -[UIWindow setScreen:] should not be called if the client adopts UIScene lifecycle. Call -[UIWindow setWindowScene:] instead.**

The custom view controller does not show up in the external display.

What should I change? I want to handle both iOS 13.x and prior devices.

Comment: The error message is very precise. Did you try following its advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 13 devices, instead of setting `screen`, you should set `windowScene` on the `externalWindow` object. Before that, you should find out matching `windowScene` from `UIApplication`'s connected scenes. The revised method is as follows:

```
private func setupExternalScreen(screen: UIScreen, shouldRecurse: Bool = true) {
    // For iOS13 find matching UIWindowScene
    var matchingWindowScene: UIWindowScene? = nil
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        for aScene in scenes {
            if let windowScene = aScene as? UIWindowScene {
                // Look for UIWindowScene that has matching screen
                if (windowScene.screen == screen) {
                    matchingWindowScene = windowScene
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if matchingWindowScene == nil {
            // UIWindowScene has not been created by iOS rendered yet
            // Lets recall self after delay of two seconds
            if true == shouldRecurse {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
                    self.setupExternalScreen(screen:screen, shouldRecurse: false)
                }
            }
            // Dont proceed furthure in iOS13
            return
        }
    }

    guard externalWindow == nil, let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExternalScreen") as? ExternalScreenViewController else {
      return
    }

    externalWindow = UIWindow(frame: screen.bounds)
    externalWindow!.rootViewController = vc
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        // Set windowScene here, no need to set screen
        externalWindow!.windowScene = matchingWindowScene
    } else {
        // Set screen the traditional way
        externalWindow!.screen = screen
    }
    externalWindow!.isHidden = false

}
```

Note: we should set `isHidden` as `hidden` is deprecated.

Comment: Where is ExternalScreenViewController?